# In which functions, how to add action in index cell of LiquidFloatingActionButton?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created two button cells in LiduidFloatingActionButton with following code.

```
private func createFloatingButtons(){
    cells.append(createButtonCell("firstCell"))
    cells.append(createButtonCell("secondCell"))
    let floatingFrame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 56 - 16, y: self.view.frame.height - 56 - 36, width: 56, height: 56)
    let floatingButton = createButton(floatingFrame, style:.Up)
    self.view.addSubview(floatingButton)
    self.floatingActionButton = floatingButton
}
```

I don't know to add action in each cell of LiquidFloatingActionButton and also to display the name of cell. Please help me if anybody known about it.

Comment: Add code of createButtonCell

Comment: @jignesh Vadadoriya  you mean I have to add code in following function  private func createButtonCell(iconName:String) -> LiquidFloatingCell {
       let name = LiquidFloatingCell(icon: UIImage(named: iconName)!)
        return name
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for adding action on each cell.

```
extension CampaignListViewController: LiquidFloatingActionButtonDelegate {
func liquidFloatingActionButton(liquidFloatingActionButton: LiquidFloatingActionButton, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int){
   // floatingActionButton.didTappedCell()
    switch(index){
    case 0:
        // do something
        break;

    case 1:
        // do somthing
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    self.floatingActionButton.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function in `viewDidLoad()`. Read this GitHub code you will get more idea. https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton/blob/master/Example/LiquidFloatingActionButton/ViewController.swift

Comment: i have already call the function in viewDidLoad(). But i want to add action in each cell.